# Checking for a duplicate email

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am inserting records into a DB and i am checking for a duplicate email id,but the thing is email already exists message is displayed and the records also getting inserted into DB

My BAL

```
 public int insert(string firstname,string lastname,DateTime dob,string gender,string mobile,string country,string state,string email,string password)
    {
      ProfileMasterDAL dal=new ProfileMasterDAL();
      try
      {
          return ProfileMasterDAL.Insert(firstname, lastname, dob, gender, mobile, country, state, email, password);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

          throw ex;
      }
```

My UI

```
 try
        {

            chk = pmBLL.insert(firstname, lastname, dob, gender, mobile, country, state, email, password);

            if (chk >= 0)
            {
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Email already exists');</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                result = pmBLL.insert(firstname, lastname, dob, gender, mobile, country, state, email, password);
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    Session["username"] = TextBox1.Text;
```

my insert stored proc

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[Insertreg]

( @id int output,@FirstName varchar (50),@LastName varchar(50) ,@Dob datetime,
@Gender varchar(20) ,@MobileNo nchar(10) ,@Country varchar(50) ,
 @State varchar (50),@EmailId varchar (50),@Password nchar (15),@result int output

)
 as 
 begin

if exists(select EmailId from Profile_Master where EmailId=@EmailId)
set @result=0
else
begin
set @result=1

insert into                                                                                            Profile_Master(FirstName,LastName,Dob,Gender,MobileNo,Country,State,EmailId,Password)
 values 
(@FirstName,@LastName,@Dob,@Gender,@MobileNo,@Country,@State,@EmailId,@Password)
 set @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
 return
 end 
 end
```

Comment: The stored proc looks better now.  If the email already exists, the stored proc should return 0, otherwise it should insert a new record and return 1.  Can you explain the error better, i.e., what are you expecting to happen? and what is actually happening?

Comment: If you get an error that the email already exists, maybe it already exists.  Your original post showed code that would try to insert it even if it already existed.  Begin and end will prevent this SP from trying to insert a duplicate.

Comment: Also, your code calls pmBLL.Insert, but your SP is Insertreg.  You dont show any code mapping the insert to the SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a begin and end for your else statement

```
if exists(select @EmailId from Profile_Master where EmailId=@EmailId) 
    set @result=0 
else 
begin
    set @result=1 

    insert into Profile_Master(FirstName,LastName,Dob,Gender,MobileNo,Country,State,EmailId,Password) 
      values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Dob,@Gender,@MobileNo,@Country,@State,@EmailId,@Password) 
    set @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
end
```

Comment: Compare my sql statement to yours.  I don't set the begin/end in yours.

Answer (score 1):

suggestions

1) make unique key on email id

2) use below SP

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[Insertreg]

 ( @id int output,@FirstName varchar (50),@LastName varchar(50) ,@Dob datetime,
@Gender varchar(20) ,@MobileNo nchar(10) ,@Country varchar(50) ,
 @State varchar (50),@EmailId varchar (50),@Password nchar (15),@result int output

 )
 as 
 begin

   declare @iCount int
    select @iCount = count(EmailId) from Profile_Master where EmailId=@EmailId

  SET @result = @iCount

  if @result > 0
 BEGIN
    set @result=0
    return
     END
    ELSE
     BEGIN
     set @result=1

INSERT INTO        Profile_Master(FirstName,LastName,Dob,Gender,MobileNo,Country,State,EmailId,Password)
 values 
(@FirstName,@LastName,@Dob,@Gender,@MobileNo,@Country,@State,@EmailId,@Password)
 set @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
 return @id
 end 
    end
```

Comment: could you please share your complete stored procedure here, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this at the BAL layer, not the UI layer.

Answer (score 0):

your sql query

```
insert into                                                                                           Profile_Master(FirstName,LastName,Dob,Gender,MobileNo,Country,State,EmailId,Password)
 values 
(@FirstName,@LastName,@Dob,@Gender,@MobileNo,@Country,@State,@EmailId,@Password)
 set @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

is sepreate from condition put it any condition use begin and end in proper manner you will get the solution

```
Begin
if exists(select @EmailId from Profile_Master where EmailId=@EmailId)
set @result=0
else
 Begin set @result=1

insert into                                                                                           Profile_Master(FirstName,LastName,Dob,Gender,MobileNo,Country,State,EmailId,Password)
 values 
(@FirstName,@LastName,@Dob,@Gender,@MobileNo,@Country,@State,@EmailId,@Password)
 set @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
End
End
```

Comment: result = pmBLL.insert(firstname, lastname, dob, gender, mobile, country, state, email, password);   here i am getting result as -1 when record is inserted i dont know why?